# When customView transition animation, it can't receive gesture

Tags: ios, xcode

```
[UIView transitionWithView:imageView
                  duration:3.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{ 
                    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[welcomePhoto objectAtIndex:photoCount]];

                }
                completion:^(BOOL finish){
                }];
```

When the animation transition at the three second,
imageView can't receive custom gesture,
other times is fine.
How can i fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The reason :** when UIView animation starts from one point to another, the actual view goes to the new position straight away but it is just hidden. And the view you see moving is just an illusion.

My Given reason is based on paul hagerty's stanford lecture about animation.

The solution to this can be found in other given answer.